# Floating label doesn't look right on datalist input in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5, web-frontend

Is there a way for floating label to show up properly for datalist in Bootsrap 5? This is how it looks like right now...
It works fine without the form-floating class but I'd like to use floating form.

```
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Datalist example</label>
                    <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
                    <datalist id="datalistOptions">
                        <option value="San Francisco">
                        <option value="New York">
                        <option value="Seattle">
                        <option value="Los Angeles">
                        <option value="Chicago">
                    </datalist>
                </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISjbf.png)

Comment: Updated the code in the answer, try that

Answer (score 0):

I haven't analyzed the reason in depth, but it seems to work fine if you move the label element to the end.

```
<div class="form-floating">
    <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
    <datalist id="datalistOptions">
        <option value="San Francisco">
        <option value="New York">
        <option value="Seattle">
        <option value="Los Angeles">
        <option value="Chicago">
    </datalist>
    <label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Datalist example</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your **label after the input field**. Here is the updated code. Try this:-

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
                    <label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Datalist example</label>
                    <datalist id="datalistOptions">
                        <option value="San Francisco">
                        <option value="New York">
                        <option value="Seattle">
                        <option value="Los Angeles">
                        <option value="Chicago">
                    </datalist>
                </div>
```